# Iterating over array and adding unique parameters to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I got a issue I would like feedback on how it can be solved.

Here's my JSON:

```
  questions: [
    {
      question: 'lala',
      answer: 'papa',
      categories: ['Handla']

    },
    {
      question: 'xxxx',
      answer: 'yyyy',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    },
    {
      question: 'abcefg',
      answer: 'gooooogle',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    }
  ]
```

I want to iterate over this question array and append the **ALL** the object.categories to a new array and then filtering out the duplicated ones. So basically my response should be:

```
["Handla", "Reklamation"]
```

Comment: Not very good duplicate at all. Here is the possible solution: `const categories = data.questions.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr.categories), []).filter((category, index, array) => array.indexOf(category) === index)`.

Comment: @dfsq That is so much more beautiful and readable than `vars cats=[]; for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var cat = questions[i].categories[0];
  if (cats.indexOf(cat) == -1) cats.push(cat);
}` - I get tears in my eyes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the ES6 `Set` you can filter duplicate values easily. You just need to flatten your categories into a single array first:

```js
const questions = [
    {
      question: 'lala',
      answer: 'papa',
      categories: ['Handla']

    },
    {
      question: 'xxxx',
      answer: 'yyyy',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    },
    {
      question: 'abcefg',
      answer: 'gooooogle',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    }
  ];
const flattened = questions.reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr.categories], []); // ['Handla', 'Reklamation', 'Reklamation']
const unique = Array.from(new Set(flattened));
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `map()` method and ES6 `Set` and spread syntax `...`

```js
const data = {"questions":[{"question":"lala","answer":"papa","categories":["Handla"]},{"question":"xxxx","answer":"yyyy","categories":["Reklamation"]},{"question":"abcefg","answer":"gooooogle","categories":["Reklamation"]}]}

const result = [...new Set([].concat(...data.questions.map(o => o.categories)))]
console.log(result)
```

Or instead of `map()` you can use `reduce()` and use `Set` as accumulator parameter.

```js
const data = {"questions":[{"question":"lala","answer":"papa","categories":["Handla"]},{"question":"xxxx","answer":"yyyy","categories":["Reklamation"]},{"question":"abcefg","answer":"gooooogle","categories":["Reklamation"]}]}

const result = [...data.questions.reduce((r, e) => {
  return r.add(...e.categories), r
}, new Set)]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps. Reduce questions to array of all categories and then filter unique items. Something like this:

```js
const data = {
  questions: [{
      question: 'lala',
      answer: 'papa',
      categories: ['Handla']

    },
    {
      question: 'xxxx',
      answer: 'yyyy',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    },
    {
      question: 'abcefg',
      answer: 'gooooogle',
      categories: ['Reklamation']
    }
  ]
}

const categories = data.questions
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr.categories), [])
  .filter((category, index, array) => array.indexOf(category) === index)

console.log(categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all categories in an array and take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique values.

```js
var questions= [{ question: 'lala', answer: 'papa', categories: ['Handla'] }, { question: 'xxxx', answer: 'yyyy', categories: ['Reklamation'] }, { question: 'abcefg', answer: 'gooooogle', categories: ['Reklamation'] }],
    unique = [...new Set(questions.reduce((r, { categories: c }) => r.concat(c), []))];
  
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain old JS working on many more browsers

```js
var cats = [], questions = [{question: 'lala',answer: 'papa',categories: ['Handla']},{question: 'xxxx',answer: 'yyyy',categories: ['Reklamation']},{question: 'abcefg',answer: 'gooooogle',categories: ['Reklamation']}];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var cat = questions[i].categories[0];
  if (cats.indexOf(cat) == -1) cats.push(cat);
}
console.log(cats);
```

A bit more modern:

```js
const questions = [{question: 'lala',answer: 'papa',categories: ['Handla']},{question: 'xxxx',answer: 'yyyy',categories: ['Reklamation']},{question: 'abcefg',answer: 'gooooogle',categories: ['Reklamation']}];
let cats = [];

questions.forEach(function(q) {
  var cat = q.categories[0];
  if (cats.indexOf(cat) == -1) cats.push(cat);
});
console.log(cats);
```